# CallKit native screen Speaker button is toggled automatically

Tags: ios, avaudiosession, callkit

I'm using CallKit in my VoIP app but when I tap on the speaker button in the native screen, the button is toggled automatically by itself.

I tried breaking out everything (now I don't use my calling service layer, only callkit). And I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: I have the same issue but I didn't have the time to dig into it. It seems to be a common issue, although it's not clear if someone has managed to solve it. It's probably related to the setup and activation timing of the Audio Session. If you'll figure out how to solve the issue, please write the answer!

Comment: After a lot of research, I reached the conclusion that CallKit has some issues and yet not fixed. (especially with WebRTC). The only way I could use to reduce this effect is to use the category `duckOthers`. Give it a try.